# React HashRouter, I have a problem with the page reloading when clicking on the nav bar

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, navbar

When I try to change the page and click on the nav bar it changes to url but until I manually click on reload page it won't change.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage/HomePage';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.js';
import 'popper.js/dist/popper.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.min.css'
import { MainMenu, MainMenuItem } from './components/MainMenu/MainMenu';
import { HashRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ContactPage } from './components/ContactPage/ContactPage';
import { UserLoginPage } from './components/UserLoginPage/UserLoginPage';

const menuItems = [
  new MainMenuItem("Home", "/"),
  new MainMenuItem("Contact", "/contact"),
  new MainMenuItem("Log in", "/user/login"),
];

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MainMenu items={menuItems} />
    <HashRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route index path='/' element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactPage />} />
        <Route path="/user/login" element={<UserLoginPage />} />
     </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

This is another class that needs to align my nav bar.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { HashRouter , Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export class MainMenuItem {
  text: string = '';
  link: string = '#';

  constructor(text: string, link: string) {
    this.text = text;
    this.link = link;
  }
}

interface MainMenuProperties {
  items: MainMenuItem[];
}

interface MainMenuState {
  items: MainMenuItem[];
}

export class MainMenu extends React.Component<MainMenuProperties>{
  state: MainMenuState;

  constructor(props: Readonly<MainMenuProperties>) {  
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: props.items,
    };
  }

  public setItems(items: MainMenuItem[]) {
    this.setState({
      items: items,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        {this.state.items.map(this.makeNewLink)}
    );
  }

  private makeNewLink(item: MainMenuItem, index: number) {
    return (
      <Link key={index} to={item.link} className='nav-link'>
        {item.text}
      </Link>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at the https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help page and only apply relevant formatting, at the moment some of your code appears to be escaped and it's unclear if that was an issue posting, or in the original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering the application links (*`Link`*) in `MainMenu` which is rendering it's own router while the routes you want to navigate to are rendered in their own `HashRouter` in the `index.js`.

You need only one router per app, and all React-Router components (*`Link`, `Route`, etc*) and hooks (*`useLocation`, etc*).

1. Remove `HashRouter` from `MainMenu`.
2. Move `MainMenu` into the main `HashRouter`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

...

export class MainMenu extends React.Component<MainMenuProperties>{
  state: MainMenuState;

  constructor(props: Readonly<MainMenuProperties>) {  
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: props.items,
    };
  }

  public setItems(items: MainMenuItem[]) {
    this.setState({
      items,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        {this.state.items.map(this.makeNewLink)}
      </Container>
    );
  }

  private makeNewLink(item: MainMenuItem, index: number) {
    return (
      <Link key={index} to={item.link} className='nav-link'>
        {item.text}
      </Link>
    );
  }
}
```

```
const menuItems = [
  new MainMenuItem("Home", "/"),
  new MainMenuItem("Contact", "/contact"),
  new MainMenuItem("Log in", "/user/login"),
];

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HashRouter>
      <MainMenu items={menuItems} />
      <Routes>
        <Route index path='/' element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactPage />} />
        <Route path="/user/login" element={<UserLoginPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```